# Removing a widget via theme editor

Tags: themes, widgets, templates

I recently updated our company's website and now we are seeing our newsletter sign-up widget appearing on landing pages where it previously had not. Our landing page template is set up to remove this widget. I have changed none of this code. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the widget from Apperances > Widgets page on your WordPress menu. Have you tried that yet?

Also, if you are using the Genesis theme from StudioPress, you and can't find a suitable way to remove it, try inspecting the widget element, see what CSS ID or class is controlling it and check the functions.php to comment it out from the file.